# Scraping a series of URLs in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, download

I'm trying to batch download a series of URLs. So far my code is

```
link <- paste("http://portal.hud.gov/hudportal/documents/huddoc? id=RAD_PHAApp_", state, ".xls", sep = "")
state <- c('al','tx')
download.file(link, paste(destfile = 'Y:\\PBlack\\RAD\\', state, '.xls', sep = ""), mode = 'wb')
```

The idea here that I could add names to the state value and it would download and name them the state.

R returns the following when I run the code.

```
Warning messages:
1: In download.file(link, paste(destfile = "Y:\\PBlack\\RAD\\", state,  :
 only first element of 'url' argument used
2: In download.file(link, paste(destfile = "Y:\\PBlack\\RAD\\", state,  :
 only first element of 'destfile' argument used
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be a space between `huddoc?` and `id` in the first URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As TARehman points out, you need to have separate calls to download.file for each file. It might be more intuitive for you to do this with a for loop.

Also, using paste0 will avoid using the sep="" every time.

```
states <- c('al', 'tx')

for(state in states) {
  link <- paste0("http://portal.hud.gov/hudportal/documents/huddoc?id=RAD_PHAApp_", state, ".xls")
  download.file(link,paste0("~/Desktop/",state,".xls"),mode='wb')
}
```

Though mapply might be somewhat faster.

Comment: Got this to work thanks! So far I can understand this level of code, so I like this function. Helps me learn a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the command to save the files more than once. Right now it will not work because the `download.file()` function downloads a single file, not a vector of files.

As so:

```
states <- c('al','tx')
links <- paste("http://portal.hud.gov/hudportal/documents/huddoc?id=RAD_PHAApp_", states, ".xls", sep = "")

func.download_files <- function(link,state) {

    download.file(link,paste("~/Desktop/",state,".xls",sep=""),mode='wb')
}

mapply(FUN = func.download_files,link=links,state=states)
```

Comment: Tried running this code. On the other hand I made a data.frame that contains all of the state names I need (ex. 'AL', 'TX', 'MA)

    links <- paste("http://portal.hud.gov/hudportal/documents/huddoc?     id=RAD_PHAApp_", states, ".xls", sep = "")
    func.download_files <- function(link, state) {
       download.file(link,paste("C:/Users/VT8575P/Desktop/", state,".xls",sep     =""), mode ='wb')
    }
    mapply(FUN = func.download_files,link=links,state = states) 

R returns

Comment: Warning message:
In download.file(link, paste("C:/Users/VT8575P/Desktop/", state,  :
  only first element of 'destfile' argument used

Comment: You still have a space between `huddoc?` and `id=RAD_PHAApp_` first of all. If you made `states` into a data.frame then this will not work; the function expects that `states` will be a vector.